# Find common rows on two gzipped files

Tags: text-processing, gzip, file-comparison

I've got two big gzip files. I need to find the common rows. Zgrep (gzip) does this to a large extent like `zgrep -f <unzipped file> <zipped file>` but I can't find any switches to do `zgrep -f <zipped file> <zipped file>`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

It is much more efficient to `gunzip(1)`, then `sort(1)` the files and use `comm(1)` on the result.

Comment: +1. I discovered `comm` during a few hours of waiting on fgrep to finish :)

Comment: @joepd, $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3):

GNU `grep(1)` can't do what you want, but you can get similar results using process substitution, if your system and shell support it:

```
$ grep -f <(gunzip < zipped_patterns.txt.gz) zipped_data.txt.gz
```

By using input redirection (`gunzip < file.gz`) within the process substitution, `gunzip(1)` decompresses the file in memory, without writing the decompressed data to disk. If your patterns file is sufficiently large compared to available RAM, this may well cause the system to thrash. As [vonbrand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253958/16160) points out, sorting your files and using `comm(1)` will be much more efficient.